# How to fix wsl error when running docker?

Tags: docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux

i'm having a trouble with wsl. When i try to install ubuntu i always see thí error

Installing, this may take a few minutes...

NslRegisterDistribution failed with error: 0x80370114

Error: 0x80370114 The operation could not be started because a required feature is not installed.

Press any key to continue...

I also turn on hyper-v, virtual machine, subsystem but it had no impact :D I hope you can help me to fix this